# Reading a text file from the command line C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, text-files

If someone can help me get past this roadblock that would be amazing. I am trying to open a text file called "inputfile.txt" and I can not! Every example I have looked at has worked fine, but when I try to use it, the file returns null and I get a segmentation fault. 
Note, this is prior to error checking

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *inputPtr;
    inputPtr = fopen(argv[2], "r");
    fclose(inputPtr);
}
```

I realized that I "goofed" slightly, when I first created the text files on my desktop I titled it "inputfile.txt", but it was saved as "inputfile.txt.txt" as odd as that is!

Comment: Can you add a line before `fopen` line and share the result? `printf("Args = %d, File name %s\n", argc, argc > 2 ? argv[2] : "OOB);"` Also adding `return 0;` at end is a good idea.

Comment: @MohitJain lol i have that later on in my code with error checking as well. The output was : Args = 4, File name inputfile.txt

Comment: and then the failed to open and segmentation fault (core dumped) afterwards

Comment: `fclose` should never be given a null pointer. So always check. Do you have file `inputfile.txt` in your current directory?

Comment: yes it is in the same directory, but I commented it out and ran the program again and it did not work still

Comment: Can you double confirm by running following program `fclose(fopen("test.txt", "w"));` and see if file appears in the same directory? Or you can test by using fill path of "inputfile.txt".

Comment: @MohitJain please refer to my edit in the original question lol. thanks for your help

Comment: You should always add a check after fopen if the file has been opened or not with 'if ( inputPtr!=NULL )' and if it equal to NULL i.e. the file did not open for whatever reason, do not use 'fclose(inputPtr)'.

Comment: it should be trivially easy to rename the file: `inputfile.txt.txt` to `inputfile.txt`

Answer (score 1):

Well the first big problem is that you do not check the value of `argc`. This value is set to the number of arguments that were passed to the programm. By default argc is at least 1, because 1 argument is always passed. If you pass any additional arguments, argc must be greater than 1. In your case, i guess it should be 2. 
The second problem comes from the first. The numbering of array elements in C starts from 0, so if your programm accepts `argc` arguments, `argv` which keeps the arguments will have `argc` elements, BUT!!! the last element will have an index of `argc-1`. By default, if no additional arguments were passed only `argv[0]` exists and it is the name of the programm, it is also always passed, hence argc is always at least 1.

In your case, if `argc==2`, then argv[2] simply does not exist, only `argv[0]`, and `argv[1]` exist. And when you pass one argument to the programm, it will be kept in argv[1]. That means that this line `inputPtr = fopen(argv[2], "r");` should be changed to this `inputPtr = fopen(argv[1], "r");`. Also there should be a check of argc at the beginning of the programm. soome thing along the lines of

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  if(argc!=2)
  {
    printf("Wrong number of arguments\n");
    return -1;
  }
.....
}
```

Comment: the program is supposed to have argc=4 with a.out, a character, input file, output file in that order. I don't understand why this isn't working because it works everywhere else I have seen this

Comment: well you should really check it if it actually does have these 4 arguments for starters, because maybe, just maybe it does not.

Comment: thank you, thats a good suggestion, but I realized I made an error by saving the text file as "inputfile.txt.txt" lol thanks for your help!!

Comment: If it still fails, then as said in comments above, you should also really really check what `fopen(argv[2], "r");` returns, because fclose sholdn't be given a NULL pointer.

Answer (score 0):

before accessing anything beyond `argv[0]` (which is always available)

the code must check the value of `argc` to assure the command line parameter actually exists.

Note;  in C, array indexs start from 0 through (count of array entries -1).

So if `argc` is 2, then there is only one command line parameter and:

1. `argv[0]` is the executing program name
2. `argv[1]` is the first parameter.
3. `argv[2]` is a NULL pointer.

so using `argv[2]` is accessing address 0 and will result in

1. undefined behaviour
2. lead to a seg fault event